# How can I kill a running process in Linux, kill -9/-15 is not working, no effect at all

Tags: linux, file, unix, kill-process

When I try to install miniconda on the server, it gets stuck and I closed the terminal and start a new one. I try to remove the old miniconda directory but got error, it says *device or resource busy*, so I use lsof +D directory to find the running process, it is:

```
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF        NODE NAME
conda.exe 32565 qp24  cwd    DIR   0,55       50 25778411266 miniconda3
```

But the weird thing is that I could not be able to kill the PID using either kill -9 32565 or kill -15 32565. It literally has no effect: (the process is not tagged as zombie as well)

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND    
32565 qp24      20   0       0      0      0 R 100.0  0.0  5124187h conda.exe
```

Basically, I don't know how to handle this situation, do I need to reboot the server? Because our admin is not around, a quick reboot is not possible. Wonder do you guys have any suggestions to kill this process?

Comment: Weird, a process without memory (VIRT == RES == 0) that uses 100% CPU. Does kill exit with an exit code unequal zero?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. No, when I call kill -9 32565 or kill -15 32565, no return/exit message at all.

Comment: In order to display the exit code, you enter `echo $?` just after executing the kill. Generally Unix/Linux utilities aren't very verbose. Sometimes they don't even complain if something's wrong. What confuses me a little is the name of the program. It isn't very common (but not forbidden either) to use an extension.

Comment: Thanks very much for the hint, I tried echo $?, the exit code it gives me is 0

Comment: Does the process respond to stopping it? `kill -STOP <pid>`. Afterwards the state of the process should show a T (and the CPU consumption should be zero). In ancient times I had problems with an SCSI driver that put processes in an uninteruptable sleep (State D), with no other option than to reboot. This doesn't seem to be the case with your issue

Comment: Hi, I tried with the command kill -STOP 32565, nothing really changed... still the same as before....):

Comment: OK, I understand you see no changes in the state column (S, next to SHR). Obviously the Linux kernel can't change the state of the process. Neither SIGKILL nor SIGSTOP can be caught by the process itself, hence it is only kernel code that is executed.. This makes it likely that you have found a bug in Linux. I leave it up to you to decide if you want to report the bug, but as I see it, you won't get rid of the culprit without a reboot.